# Conversion of HttpClient written in java to C# FOR calling Web apis

Tags: java, c#

I am extremely new to C# And windows app programming.

I am trying to create an AsyncTask, like in java , where i can query a url and get its response back.

Here is the code i usually use in java, i want to implement the copy in C sharp.

```
public interface ResponseCallback 
{
    void onSuccess(String response);
    void onFailure(String exception);
}

public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> 
{
    private ResponseCallback myResponse = null;
    private int type = 0;//POST
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = null;
    StringEntity entity = null;

    private HttpResponse response = null;

    public MyAsyncTask(String url,ResponseCallback myResponse)
    {
        this.myResponse = myResponse;
        this.execute(url);
    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... param) 
    {
        String url = param[0];

        response = null;
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httpclient.getParams().setParameter("http.connection-manager.timeout", 15000);
        try {

            if (type == 0)
            {
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
                if (nameValuePairs != null)
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                if (entity != null)
                    httppost.setEntity(entity);

                response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            }
            else
            {
                HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(url);
                response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException es) 
        {   
        } catch (IOException e) 
        {
        }
        String resp = null;
        if (response != null)
        {
            try {
                  resp = Utilities.convertStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent());
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return resp;
        }
        else
            return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String resp) 
    {
        if (resp != null)
        {          
            if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == Constants.RESULT_OK )
            {
                try {
                      myResponse.onSuccess(resp.trim());
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                }
            }
            else
                 myResponse.onFailure(resp);
        }
        else
            myResponse.onFailure(resp);
    }
}
```

I have tried this in C #. Anyone wanna help me fix few things in this code and give me some info, what to do next

```
namespace The_Vow.Global
{
    class MyAsyncTask
    {
        public ResponseCallback callback;

        static void queryUrl(String url)
        {
            RunAsync(url).Wait();
        }

        static async Task RunAsync(String url)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("MY_IP");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                // HTTP GET
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
                //response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/products", gizmo);

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    String jsonStr = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

// callback variable is not being recognized????
callback.onSuccess(jsonStr);

                    //Console.WriteLine("{0}\t${1}\t{2}", product.Name, product.Price, product.Category);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}


    namespace The_Vow.Global
    {
            public interface ResponseCallback
            {
                void onSuccess(String response);
                void onFailure(String exception);
            }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that it will meet all your needs, but I would look into using [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx), specifically the `...Async` functions available in that class, to download asynchronously.

Comment: @MichaelTodd there are few points, i wanted to inspect, first i can't call callback.onSuccess(jsonStr); why can't i use the variable? secondly, the correct way of getting response string

Comment: Did you set the callback function? Where?

Comment: @MichaelTodd i have an interface and also a variable defined in MyAsyncTask, check how am i using interfaces in java

Comment: If the 'callback variable is not being recognized' then the fault lies with setting the callback variable. I would look into resolving that issue first, then worry about whether or not your HttpClient conversion has been successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `callback` field is an **instance field**, so you can't access it from a **static method**, unless you make the field static.

Another alternative I would like to recommend though, is not using a field at all. Pass the callback variable as a method argument.

Or you can stop using **static** methods at all, make them **instance** methods.